# Question about proof " every perfect set is uncountable.".

Tags: real-analysis

This is my proof refer to baby rudin Thm 2.43.
Let $P$ is perfect set, then $P$ is infinite set.(Because P don't have any isolated point.)
If $P$ is countable $P$ should be represented by 
$$P=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots \}$$
Now labeling following way, Because P is non-empty
,$\exists x_1\in P$,

Let a arbitrary neighborhood $N_{r_1}(x_1)$.

Since every point in $P$ is limit point of $P$.
$\exists x_2 \in P$.

Let $r_2=\frac{1}{2}\min(d(x_1,x_2),r_1-d(x_1,x_2))$

Then $(i)\bar{N}_{r_2}(x_2)\subset N_{r_1}(x_1)$, ($\bar{N}$ imply closure of N) 
,$(ii) x_1\notin N_{r_2}(x_2)$,$(iii)N_{r_2}(x_2)\cap P\neq \emptyset$
similar way we can make sequence $\{N_{r_n}(x_n)\}$ satisfying

$(i)\bar{N}_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})\subset N_{r_n}(x_n)$
,$(ii) x_n\notin N_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})$,$(iii)N_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})\cap P\neq \emptyset$

Let $K_n:=\bar{N}_{r_n}(x_n)\cap P$, then P is closed set, and $\bar{N}_{r_n}(x_n)$ is closed and bounded, so $K_n$ is closed subset of compact set, therefore, $K_n$ is compact.

$\forall n\in N$, $K_n$ is non-empty compact set satisfying $K_{n+1}\in K_n$,
so  $\bigcap_{n\in N}K_n\neq \emptyset.$
Otherwise, $x_n\notin K_{n+1}$, so there should be exist $y\neq x_n, \forall n\in N$, $y\in\bigcap_{n\in N}K_n$. $P$ is not represented by $\{x_n\}$, so P is uncountable.

Here is question,
I don't know what is difference between above proof and following,

For $x_1\in N$, every sequence,$x_{n+1}=x_n+2$ is not represented $N$ perfectly, so $N$ is uncountable.

what is the difference of two proofs?, or If my proof  for" every perfect set is uncountable." is not exact, where is exact proof?

Comment: I think you can conclude that a perfect set is infinite because it has no isolated points. Not because it is closed. Because every finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, but it is not perfect. At least, as far as I have read about perfect sets.

Comment: This is my fault,

Comment: Also, how can you conclude (i)? Suppose your $P = \left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Take $x_1 = \dfrac{1}{4}$ with $r_1 = \dfrac{1}{1000}$ and then take $x_2 = \dfrac{3}{4}$, then you will not have the closure of neighbourhood of $x_2$ as a subset of neighbourhood of $x_1$.

Comment: Also, I am thinking of using the Hausdroff property of metric spaces to get a contradiction. However, the infimum would create a problem when constructing a neighburhood to prove a point to be isolated.

Comment: According to my proof, we should select $x_2$ in $[\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2000},\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2000}]$.

Comment: I didn't learn the Hausdroff property of metric spaces. Can you explain it more easily?

Comment: Housdroff Property states that if you have two distinct points, then you can have two disjoint open spheres centered at these two given points. Now, if you can use this property to somehow come to a contradiction that at least one of the points of your set (considered countable) is isolated, then the proof is through!

Comment: I understand what Housdroff Property, but I can't find any contradiction.  Can you give me some more hints,

Comment: It's certainly not an easy proof. If I recall correctly, Rudin left out many important details.